# How to add picturebox to Matlab App Designer?

Tags: image, matlab, picturebox, matlab-app-designer

I want to add picture in my Matlab UI application made with App Designer. I there any way how to add picture box or something? Thank you.

edit: I know only about adding picture to button, but cannot find any other way.

Comment: MATLAB displays images on axes objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = uifigure;
im = uiimage(f);
im.ImageSource = 'imagename.png';
```

Comment: Hi CarSmyth, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add a little more context about why this is the correct way to do it, or even links to documentation? Thanks!